# recursive implementation of reconstructing Binary search tree from preorder array in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, binary-tree

problem: Given a pre-order array turn it into Binary search tree

```
                 7
           5          9
       3      6    8     10
```

Solution:

step 1: convert the array into Stack

The first element poped from stack is root.

compare it with the next element, if it is less than the root value, make it a left subtree
if not make it a right subtree

here is the code

```
public class reconstruct{
  public static void main(String[] args){

            Stack s = new Stack();
            Integer[] arr = {7,5,3,6,9,8,10};
            List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(arr);


            for (int i=arr.length-1; i>=0;i--){
                s.push(arr[i]);
            }

            System.out.println(s);
            Node newone = CreateFromPreOrder(s);
            printInorder(newone);





public static Node CreateFromPreOrder(Stack preOrder) {

            if (!preOrder.isEmpty()) {
                //System.out.println("hel");

            int value = (int) preOrder.pop();




            Node root = new Node(value);
            if (!preOrder.isEmpty()){

            if((int)preOrder.peek()<value){
                root.left=CreateFromPreOrder(preOrder);
            }
            else 
                  root.right = CreateFromPreOrder(preOrder);

        }
            return root;
            }
            else return null;

            } 

public static void printInorder(Node root) {

            if (root!=null){
                printInorder(root.left);
                System.out.print(" " + root.data);
                printInorder(root.right);
            }
        }
    }
```

`Output:
[10, 8, 9, 6, 3, 5, 7]
 3 6 8 10 9 5 7`

The output is not inorder array that is expected. I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the logic above.

Comment: Not a solution to this question, but anyone who answers this can please let me know **Would sorting the array and then creating a binary search tree from that work ? if not why?**

Comment: You'll get a unbalanced tree. If you have a sorted array [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] you'll get the tree 1 2 3 4 5 (all on the right subtree) which is just a straight line and not a tree structure.

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun Not that I am talking about this approach http://leetcode.com/2010/11/convert-sorted-array-into-balanced.html

Comment: is [10, 8, 9, 6, 3, 5, 7] your input array?

Comment: my input array is `Integer[] arr = {7,5,3,6,9,8,10};`, but I convert into stack

Answer (score 2):

I haven't read the code to detail, but from your description, the following statement is wrong :

> The first element poped from stack is root.
>
> compare it with the next element, if it is less than the root value,
>   make it a left subtree if not make it a right subtree

Consider the following situation :

```
     7
   5
 3
```

Now, we're inserting 6. According to you, the tree should look like this :

```
     7
   5
 3
  6
```

If you take the input array vice versa, you'll face the same situation at this point :

```
     10
8
   9
  6
```

Which is not a valid binary search tree. To make this work, you need traverse the tree back up and verify the BST invariant.

If you want to reconstruct the tree 1:1 to the original one, simply add the nodes to the tree in the same order as they're in the array. That can be done because of the pre-order structure.

Comment: what is the input array, It must be given in preorder way. not just some random orders

Comment: The pre-order array for your example tree is ```[7, 5, 3, 6, 9, 8, 10]``` and I'm talking about the same one as well.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is in this part:

```
if((int)preOrder.peek()<value){
    root.left=CreateFromPreOrder(preOrder);
}else{ 
    root.right = CreateFromPreOrder(preOrder);
}
```

The else clause is wrong. As Danstahr explained, you aren't checking the BST invariant. If the next item is greater than the current node's parent, it doesn't get added to the right here.

So something like this will work (pseudo code is pseudo code):

```
public Node createTree(Parent,curNode, Stack){
    if(stack empty){
       return null;
    }

    if(Stack.peek().value<curNode.value){
        curNode.left=createTree(curNode,node made from stack.pop,Stack)
    }

    if(stack not empty and next stack item is less than my parent, or I have no parent){
        curNode.right=createTree(curNode,node made from stack.pop,Stack)    
    }

    return curNode;

}
```